# Check if 2 arrays contain the same element

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, restricted-complexity

Write a program which will take for input 2 integer arrays and return a truthy value if there exists an element which is present in both of arrays, or a falsy one otherwise. The obvious solution to this problem would be to iterate through each element in the first array and compare it against each element in the second, but here's the catch: Your program must have an algorithmic complexity of at most, in the worst case, O(NlogN), where N is the length of the longer array,

Test cases:

```
 {1,2,3,4,-5},{5,7,6,8} -> false
 {},{0}                 -> false
 {},{}                  -> false
 {1,2},{3,3}            -> false
 {3,2,1},{-4,3,5,6}     -> true
 {2,3},{2,2}            -> true
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Are the integers bound/small like in your example? E.g. is radixsort or a bitmap possible?

Comment: @Pavel The complexity depends very much on the set implementation, as far as I can tell. `O(n log n)` is doable in general, but the clarification about only handling native integers means that in some languages with limited integer ranges a linear solution is possible (e.g. by a 2^64 size lookup table)

Comment: By the way, I think that all hash-based solutions with arbitrary precision ranges should have to demonstrate that no collisions are possible or some other property to guarantee satisfaction of the requirement, because I'm not convinced about some of these answers... (with the current rules)

Comment: If the first array (N elements) is sorted it is Nlog(N) if for each element of 2 array search using "binary search" in 1 array it would be nlog(N) so the total is Nlog(N)+nlog(N)=(N+n)log(N) that is > to Nlog(N) claimed from the question ... So would remain "ascii tables"?

Comment: @RosLuP NLogN+NLogN is still O(NLogN)

Comment: I would not recommend accepting answers so quickly. It's recommended to wait at least for a week before accepting an answer.

Comment: @erikthegolfer yeah, who's going to beat a one byte solution?

Comment: @Pavel Did you notice that I removed the "The" from my name (I just now saw your reply)? A week is usually considered to be the norm before accepting an answer (although I use 14 days). It's your choice after all, but I think it's good practice to wait before you accept, because, *technically*, a 0-byte answer is also possible in a programming language that is buried deep on the internet and nobody except its creator knows about it (and in fact fits our definition of a programming language).

Comment: @Pavel Personally, I'm concerned about the validity of answers instead, because I'm not convinced most of the hash-based answers are valid (e.g. all the Python ones - see comments on the Actually answer)...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## [Actually](http://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 1 byte

```
∩
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=4oip&input=ezEsMn0KezMsM30)

This is merely the set intersection built-in. The resultant value is the intersection of the two sets - a non-empty list (which is a truthy value) if there is an intersection, and an empty list (which is a falsey value) otherwise.

### Complexity

According to the [Python Wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#set), set intersection has a worst-case time complexity of `O(N*M)` (where `N` and `M` are the lengths of the two sets). However, the time complexity is only that bad when the two sets contain distinct objects that all have the same hash value (for example, `{"some string"} & {hash("some string")}`). Since the set elements are only integers in this case (and no two integers hash to the same value unless they are equal), the actual worst-case complexity is `O(min(N, M))` (linear in the length of the smaller of the two sets). The construction of each set is `O(N)` (linear in the number of elements), so the overall complexity is `O(max(N, M))` (the complexity is dominated by the construction of the larger set).

Comment: That's not a ASCII character, takes 3 bytes in UTF-8

Comment: @Kh40tiK Actually uses [CP437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437#Characters) for encoding.

Comment: This can't possibly be O(min(N, M)). It takes O(max(M,N)) time simply to *read in* both arrays! Somehow I doubt set intersection can be done that quickly, either.

Comment: @ais523 You're partly right - I forgot to account for the time complexity of the construction of the sets. Set intersection via a hash table with no collisions absolutely can be done in linear time.

Comment: Right, I just figured that out too. *Set* intersection is indeed O(min(N, M)); but converting the arrays to sets takes O(max(N, M)) time. So we were both right.

Comment: The entire point of the complexity restriction was to prevent 1 or 2 byte solutions... Guess I underestimated the power of golfing languages.

Comment: I don't think the comment about "no two integers hash to the same value unless they are equal" is correct, especially for sufficiently large integers.

Comment: @Sp3000 Unless I read the source code wrong, `int.__hash__` simply returns the `int`.

Comment: @Mego From memory, that's only true for small ints. At the very least, `hash(10**10) != 10**10` in Python 2.7.11 and 3.5.2.

Comment: @Sp3000 `hash` truncates the object's `__hash__` value.

Comment: @Mego As far as I can tell, this doesn't seem to be true, although on some Python versions/environments you might have to go higher than 10**10 to see a difference. Compare https://tio.run/#YS2Nl and changing one of the set initialisation lines to using `*(2**61)` instead of `*(2**61-1)`. The only way I see this answer working is if there's a specific Python version where this works that I've missed, in which case it should be stated.

Comment: This is a pretty weird situation, because Python's being penalised for supporting integers. Perl doesn't, so it has a lower complexity for the same algorithm, because the choice of language is redefining what the problem is! We might need some rules on what counts as an integer, in order to make the problem fair. (Also, on whether randomized algorithms count if they run in O(n log n) for very high probability on any input; most languages have hash tables that work like that nowadays.)

Comment: Works in Dyalog APL too :-D

Comment: @Mego: Integers do not all hash to their own value. You're looking at the Python 2 `int` source code, `intobject.c`, when you should be looking at `longobject.c`, the code for the Python 3 `int` type and the Python 2 `long` type. Also, while `hash` does modify the output of `__hash__` if it's out of range, it is this modified value, not the original `__hash__` output, that is used for indexing into a dict or set's internal hash table.

Comment: Additionally, even if it were the case that all input integers had distinct hashes, you could still get quadratic runtime due to inputs with distinct hashes still mapping to the same hash table slot.

Comment: I'm not convinced it's possible to construct two integer sets whose intersection is worse than `O(n log n)` in Python 3 - it seems to me that only sets with non-numeric types will suffer from quadratic complexity. Perhaps someone who is smarter than me can look through the [CPython source](https://github.com/python/cpython) and prove me wrong.

Comment: @Mego Unless I've done something wrong, the tio.run link I provided was meant to be an example.

Comment: @Mego: Depending on the details of your Python interpreter, one of `{i * (2**64-1) for i in range(100000)}` or `{i * (2**32 - 2) for i in range(100000)}` should produce quadratic runtime, with all elements hashing to the same value. It's trickier but still possible to construct an example that causes quadratic runtime without equal hashes, by inducing large numbers of probe collisions.

Answer (score 3):

## TSQL, <s>40</s> <s>37</s> 36 bytes

SQL doesn't have arrays, it is using tables instead

Returns -1 for true or 0 for false

```sql
DECLARE @ table(a INT)
DECLARE @2 table(b INT)

INSERT @ values(1),(2),(3),(4),(-5)
INSERT @2 values(5),(6),(7),(8)

SELECT~-sign(min(abs(a-b)))FROM @,@2
```

**[Try it out](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1086537/check-if-2-arrays-contain-the-same-element)**

Comment: Yes! that's glorious

Comment: Does the execution plan generated for this query actually have the necessary runtime behavior?

Comment: @user2357112 a valid point. This does not scale well, I had to cut some corners to keep it short. Can we keep it between you and me... and the rest of the world ?

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 25+1 = 26 bytes in collaboration with Dada

```perl
print 2<($a{$_}|=$.)for@F
```

Run with `-a` (1 byte penalty).

An improved version of the program below (which is kept around to see the history of the solution, and to show the solution I found by myself; it also has more explanation). The `-a` option reads space-separated arrays as the input, storing them in `@F`. We use the `%a` dictionary (accessed as `$a{$_}`) to store a bitmask of which input arrays the input is in, and print `1` every time we see an element in both arrays, i.e. a value higher than 2 inside the resulting bitmask (fortunately, a failing comparison returns the null string, so the `print` does nothing). We can't use `say` because a newline is truthy in Perl. Performance is asymptotically the same as the older version of the program (but faster in terms of constant factors).

## Perl, 44+1 = 45 bytes

```perl
$a{"+$_"}|=$.for split}{$_={reverse%a}->{3}
```

Run with `-p` (1 byte penalty). Input one array per line, separating the elements by spaces.

This works via creating a hash table `%a` that stores a bitmask of the input arrays that a value has been seen in. If it's been seen in both the array on line 1 and on line 2, the bitmask will therefore store the value 3. Reversing the hash and seeing if 3 has a corresponding key lets us know if there are any values in common.

The complexity of this algorithm is O(n) if you consider hash creation to be constant time (it is, if you have bounded integers, like Perl does). If using bignum integers (which could be input into this program, as it leaves the input as a string), the complexity of the algorithm itself would nominally be O(n log n) for each hash creation, and O(n) for the hash reversal, which adds up to O(n log n). However, Perl's hashing algorithm suffers from potential O(n²) performance with maliciously selected input; the algorithm is randomized, though, to make it impossible to determine what that input is (and it's possible that it can't be triggered simply with integers), so it's debatable what complexity class it "morally" counts with. Luckily, this doesn't matter in the case where there's only finitely many possible distinct elements in the array.

This code will work for input other than integers, but it won't work for more than two arrays (because the `3` is hardcoded and because input on the third line wouldn't bitmask correctly, as it isn't a power of 2). Rather annoyingly, the code naturally returns one of the duplicate elements, which is truthy in *almost* all cases, but `"0"` is falsey in Perl and a valid duplicate element in the array. As such, I had to waste three bytes prepending a `+` to the output, which is the cheapest way I found to give a truthy output in the edge case of the arrays overlapping at `0`. If I'm allowed to use notions of truthy and falsey from a language other than Perl (in which any nonempty string is truthy), you can change `"+$_"` to `$_` to save three bytes.

Comment: `perl -apE '$\|=($a{$_}|=$.)==3for@F}{'` should have the same behavior for 17 less bytes ;-)

Comment: I was unaware of the `-a` flag. That does seem to help here, doesn't it? I think you can save another two bytes, though (`$\|=}{` and `print ` are the same length, and the latter allows you to avoid the `-p` flag and thus a byte of penalties; and `==3` can be replaced by `>2` for another byte). Such a pity that `$1`, etc., are already variables, or we could save another three bytes by using the entire space of variable names as a hash table.

Comment: `-a` (and `-F`) are quite convenient on PPCG (more than on anagolf since over there it costs more)! Since you need a space after the `print`, it's the same length as `-p ... $\=}{`, but why not. (yea, it's sad we can't modify `$1` etc.)

Comment: It's a character shorter; you had `p$\|=}{` (seven characters, with the `p` being a penalty); I have `print ` (six characters, including a space). I think you missed the `|` in your calculation just there.

Comment: (Also, anagolf has a penalty of 9 for the first option, 1 for each option beyond that. It's a pretty hefty penalty, but it's nonetheless often worth paying; those options are just worth so much. Penalties are so much cheaper on PPCG that they're nearly always worth incurring.)

Comment: Hum, you're right, I seem to be unable do count up to 6, such a shame.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 37 bytes:

```
exit ($*.map{|x|eval x}.reduce:&)!=[]
```

As in the definition: "program which will take for input 2 integer arrays and return a truthy value if...", this is a program, accepts 2 arrays as strings in input, returns true or false.

as a function - 14 bytes:

```
->a,b{a&b!=[]}
```

### Complexity:

The ruby documentation of the itnersection (&) operator says "It compares elements using their hash and eql? methods for efficiency.", which I suppose is exactly what we are looking for.

Empirically:

```
$ time ruby a.rb "[*1..1000001]" "[*1000001..2000000]"

real    0m0.375s
user    0m0.340s
sys 0m0.034s

$ time ruby a.rb "[*1..2000001]" "[*2000001..4000000]"

real    0m0.806s
user    0m0.772s
sys 0m0.032s

$ time ruby a.rb "[*1..4000001]" "[*4000001..8000000]"

real    0m1.932s
user    0m1.857s
sys 0m0.073s

$ time ruby a.rb "[*1..8000001]" "[*8000001..16000000]"

real    0m4.464s
user    0m4.336s
sys 0m0.119s
```

Which seems to confirm it.

Comment: Do you have any source to support that Ruby's built-in set intersection runs in O(n log n)?

Comment: No, but the runtime seems to confirm it.

Comment: Also, you should count the function, because the other version isn't a valid program, as it doesn't print anything at all.

Answer (score 2):

## Python2 - <s>41</s> 30 bytes

```
lambda a,b:bool(set(a)&set(b))
```

Set intersection: O(min(N,M)) where N and M are the length of the sets.

Conversion from a list to a set: O(max(N,M))

- Thanks to [Jakube](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/29577/jakube) for saving 9 bytes! `set(a).intersection(b)` -> `set(a)&set(b)`
- Thanks to [Kade](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/38417/kade) for saving 2 bytes! -> removed `f=`

Comment: You can use `set(a)&set(b)` instead of calling the intersection method.

Comment: If you do what Jakube says, remove the function definition and compare the intersection to `{0}` then you can get it down to 28 bytes: `lambda a,b:set(a)&set(b)>{0}`

Comment: Actually, `{1}&{1}` is truthy, while `{1}&{2}` is falsy. You can just do `lambda a,b:a&b`.

Comment: @SeeOneRhino I would have to take input as sets then, right? Lists do not implement intersection.

Comment: @Kade Doesn't seem to work :/ I tried Python2 and Python3. Removing `f=` does work though.

Comment: @TuukkaX Ok, but you still don't need the explicit call to `bool`. On PPCG, if `bool(x)` is truthy/falsy, then `x` is also considered truthy/falsy.

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell, <s>88</s> <s>78</s> <s>77</s> 23  bytes

```
!!(diff -Inc -Ex $A $B)
```

Thanks to @briantist for shaving off a whopping 54 bytes from my original, more verbose answer by shortening `-IncludeEqual`, `-ExcludeDifferent`, and `-Not`!

```
if(-Not(diff -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent $A $B)){("false")}else{("true")}
```

I can't find the source for `Compare-Object` (`diff` is an alias for `Compare-Object`), so I'm not certain on the time complexity.

Comment: I also can't comment on complexity, but you can shorten that to 23 bytes: `!!(diff -inc -ex $A $B)`

Comment: If you specifically exclude PowerShell v5, I think you can shave off another 2 bytes bytes by using `-i` instead of `-inc`, but in 5+ the `-Information*` common parameters make `-i` ambiguous.

Comment: @briantist I wasn't aware that v5 had a stable release. I'll have to use that in the future. Thanks for the other tips as well! :)

Comment: My solution was complete; it was not meant to be put inside the `if` statement; you don't need it at all! Also v5 comes with Windows 10, and v5.1 comes with Server 2016. You can also download and install WMF5 as far back as, I believe, Windows 7/2008R2. It has been released for some time now!

Comment: Oh, well holy cow. I missed that completely. It's updated. I'll have to dabble with v5 now and pay closer attention. Thanks!

Comment: Nice to see another PowerShell user around here. Two things - without some sort of definitive time complexity evaluation for `Compare-Object`, I'm skeptical that this is O(NlogN). Second, taking input via [pre-defined variables](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8731/42963) is a no-no, so you'd need a `param($a,$b)` in front or similar.

Comment: @TimmyD For some reason I can't get the ISE to accept `param($A,$B);!!(diff -Inc -Ex $A $B)`. I think I'm stuck expanding it out to `$A=1,2;$B=2,3;!!(diff -Inc -Ex $A $B)` and hard coding the arrays in the program itself. :(

Comment: @wubs You shouldn't need the semicolon, so it's just `param($A,$B)!!(diff -Inc -Ex $A $B)` -- Then, save that as a .ps1 file and call it from the command line with the arrays as arguments, like `PS C:\Scripts>.\same-element.ps1 @(1,2) @(2,3)`

Answer (score 2):

## Axiom, 439 bytes

```
c:=0;s(x,y)==(free c;if x.1=%i and y.2=%i then(x.2<y.1=>return true;x.2>y.1=>return false;c:=1;return false);if x.2=%i and y.1=%i then(x.1<y.2=>return true;x.1>y.2=>return false;c:=1;return false);if x.1=%i and y.1=%i then(x.2<y.2=>return true;x.2>=y.2=>return false);if x.2=%i and y.2=%i then(x.1<y.1=>return true;x.1>=y.1=>return false);false);r(a,b)==(free c;c:=0;m:=[[%i,j] for j in a];n:=[[i,%i] for i in b];r:=merge(m,n);sort(s,r);c)
```

this convert the first list in a list as [[i,1], [i,2]...] the second list in a list as [[1,i], [0,i]...]
where i is the variable imaginary
than merge the 2 list, and make one sort that would find if there is one element of list 1 in the list 2
so it is at last O(N log N) where N=lenght list 1 + lenght list 2

ungolfed

```
-- i get [0,0,1,2,3] and [0,4,6,7]  and build [[%i,0],[%i,0],[%i,1],[%i,2] [%i,3],[0,%i],..[7,%i]]
c:=0
s(x:List Complex INT,y:List Complex INT):Boolean==
  free c  -- [%i,n]<[n,%i]
  if x.1=%i and y.2=%i then
    x.2<y.1=> return true 
    x.2>y.1=> return false
    c:=1
    return false
  if x.2=%i and y.1=%i then
    x.1<y.2=>return true
    x.1>y.2=>return false
    c:=1
    return false
  if x.1=%i and y.1=%i then
    x.2< y.2=>return true
    x.2>=y.2=>return false
  if x.2=%i and y.2=%i then
    x.1< y.1=>return true
    x.1>=y.1=>return false
  false


r(a,b)==
  free c
  c:=0
  m:=[[%i, j]  for j in a]
  n:=[[ i,%i]  for i in b]
  r:=merge(m,n)
  sort(s, r)
  c
```

results

```
(12) -> r([1,2,3,4,-5], [5,7,6,8]), r([],[0]), r([],[]), r([1,2],[3,3]), r([3,2,1],[-4,3,5,6]), r([2,3],[2,2])
   Compiling function r with type (List PositiveInteger,List Integer)
       -> NonNegativeInteger
   Compiled code for r has been cleared.
   Compiled code for s has been cleared.
   Compiling function r with type (List PositiveInteger,List
  PositiveInteger) -> NonNegativeInteger
   Compiled code for r has been cleared.
   Compiling function s with type (List Complex Integer,List Complex
      Integer) -> Boolean
   Compiled code for s has been cleared.

   (12)  [0,0,0,0,1,1]
                                           Type: Tuple NonNegativeInteger
```

i dont understand why it "clears" code for r and s...

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 15 bytes

```php
array_intersect
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDLasMwEEX3/orBeKHC2GnsOC3k0V2/oDvVGOFIKKXYQlIWoeTb3ZHiFupaCyHuPbrzMNqM@xejTZJkXjrv4AA8AeDA11hihRvM6wZ5jU@4xecGGoTVKj@CEp9O3kGS@GN0ZmcJXOL@gVSaalZYzek5WFGPa0LzDbVa4/aXj6C3l4mjSYgqKXYpMHLNjlagDqOwVlzbc@@ldbLzI8lqsFJ0msG0IuHoBQ/wReGy0wM4b1sjTgw@3NC3su@Gk2SRQSjrcKeQ7ojOBO03UwyKogh20M4KWDDueTBFpm/24vU1/rqBpIn/2q9hCZP900b63pNwG78B)

A PHP built-in, as a [callable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php)/lambda function.  Return is a PHP `truthy`/`falsey` testable value.  Also, per the other PHP submission, this implementation should meet the challenge complexity requirements ([StackExchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329211/php-array-intersect-efficiency/6329397#6329397)).

Answer (score 1):

### R, 23 bytes

```
sum(scan()%in%scan())>0
```

If we assume that there will always be one and only one element matching and that `1` is a truthy value (which it is in **R**), then we can write :

```
sum(scan()%in%scan())
```

which is 21 bytes.

Comment: If this is doing what I think it does (for each element in A, check whether it's in B), this has time complexity of O(n*m).

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>55</s> 51 bytes

```
<?=count(array_intersect($_GET[a],$_GET[b]))<1?0:1;
```

Usage: save in a file and call from browser:

`intersect.php?a[]=1&a[]=2&a[]=3&b[]=0&b[]=4&b[]=5` outputs `0` for `false`.

`intersect.php?a[]=1&a[]=2&a[]=3&b[]=0&b[]=4&b[]=1` outputs `1` for `true`.

About complexity, I couldn't find references but according to this [StackOverflow's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6329397/2096343) the script should be OK

Comment: Do you have any source to support that PHP's built-in set intersection runs in O(n log n)?

Comment: @MartinEnder checking it...

Answer (score 1):

## GolfScript, 1 byte

If taking the input directly as arrays on the stack is allowed, this one-byte GolfScript solution should meet the spec:

```
&
```

If text-based I/O is required, the input needs to be evaluated first, pushing the length up to *two* bytes:

```
~&
```

Both of these solutions use the GolfScript array intersection operator, which is implemented using [the corresponding operator in Ruby](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Array.html#method-i-26).  They return an empty array (which is falsy) if the arrays contain no matching elements, or a non-empty array (which is truthy) containing all the matching elements otherwise.

I have so far not been able to find any documentation on the internal implementation or asymptotic complexity of the Ruby array intersection operator, beyond the brief statement that "It compares elements using their hash and eql? methods for efficiency."  However, a reasonable implementation using hash tables would run in O(*n*) time (assuming that hashing and comparisons are O(1)), and some quick performance testing suggests that this is indeed the case:

[image: Log-log plot of execution time vs. input size]

These tests were carried out using the GolfScript program `~2?.2*,/&`, which takes an integer *k*, generates an arithmetic sequence of 2 × 2<sup>*k*</sup> elements, split it into two arrays of 2<sup>*k*</sup> elements and computes their (obviously empty) intersection.  The red stars show the measured execution time *t* in seconds (on a logarithmic scale) for various values of *k*, while the green line plots the function *t* = *c* × 2<sup>*k*</sup>, where the scaling constant *c* ≈ 2<sup>−17.075</sup> was chosen to best fit the measured data.

(Note that, on a log-log plot like this, *any* polynomial function of the form *t* = *c* × (2<sup>*k*</sup>)<sup>*a*</sup> would yield a straight line.  However, the slope of the line depends on the exponent *a*, and the data is certainly consistent with *a* = 1 as shown by the green line above.  FWIW, the numerical best-fit exponent for this data set was *a* ≈ 1.00789.)

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6), 39 bytes

```
(a,b,c=new Set(b))=>a.some(e=>c.has(e))
```

Will be worse than O(n+m) but hopefully not as bad as O(n*m).

Answer (score 0):

### Rust, 103 bytes

```rs
|a:&[i32],b:&[i32]|!b.iter().collect::<std::collections::HashSet<_>>().is_disjoint(&a.iter().collect())
```

Takes two array slices (or references to full arrays, they dereference to slices automatically), bundles them up into sets, and checks for non-disjointness. I'm not quite sure how set union is implemented in the Rust standard library, but it should be O(n + m) at worst.

Without using collections, the easiest alternative I see is to sort both arrays, then step over them carefully to look for duplicates. Something like this

```rs
fn overlapping(a: &Vec<i32>, b: &Vec<i32>) -> bool{
    let mut sa = a.clone();
    sa.sort();
    let mut sb = b.clone();
    sb.sort();
    let mut ai = 0;
    let mut bi = 0;
    while ai < a.len() && bi < b.len() {
        if sa[ai] < sb[bi] {
            ai += 1;
        } else if sa[ai] > sb[bi] {
            bi += 1;
        } else{
            return true;
        }
    }
    false
}
```

But that requires too much mutation to be fun to golf in Rust IMO :)

Answer (score 0):

## Axiom, <s>50</s> 221 bytes

```
binSearch(x,v)==(l:=1;h:=#v;repeat(l>h=>break;m:=(l+h)quo 2;x<v.m=>(h:=m-1);x>v.m=>(l:=m+1);return m);0);g(a,b)==(if #a>#b then(v:=a;w:=b)else(v:=b;w:=a);c:=sort(v);for x in w repeat(if binSearch(x,c)~=0 then return 1);0)
```

ungolfed

```
--suppose v.1<=v.2<=....<=v.#v
--   binary serch of x in v, return the index i with v.i==x
--   return 0 if that index not exist
--traslated in Axiom from C  book
--Il Linguaggio C, II Edizione 
--Brian W.Kerninghan, Dennis M.Ritchie
binSearch(x,v)==
    l:=1;h:=#v  --1  4
    repeat
       l>h=>break
       m:=(l+h)quo 2   --m=(4+1)/2=5/2=2
                       --output [l,m,h]
       x<v.m=>(h:=m-1) --l x m  h =>  
       x>v.m=>(l:=m+1)
       return m
    0


g(a,b)==   
  if #a>#b then (v:=a;w:=b)
  else          (v:=b;w:=a)
  c:=sort(v)
  --output c
  for x in w repeat(if binSearch(x,c)~=0 then return 1)
  0
```

g(a,b) gets the more big array beetwin a and b; suppose it has N elements:
sort that array, do binary search with elements that other array. 
This would be O(Nlog(N)). It return 0 for no element of a in b, 1 otherwise.

results

```
(6) ->  g([1,2,3,4,-5], [5,7,6,8]), g([],[0]), g([],[]), g([1,2],[3,3]), g([3,2,1],[-4,3,5,6]), g([2,3],[2,2])
   Compiling function binSearch with type (PositiveInteger,List Integer
      ) -> NonNegativeInteger

   (6)  [0,0,0,0,1,1]
                                           Type: Tuple NonNegativeInteger
```

Comment: This works in O(n*m), doesn't it?

Comment: Yes it is O( n\*m) but above they use set intersection that is O(n\*m) too. Only my algo exit first than intersection...

Answer (score 0):

### Python, 11 bytes

```
set.__and__
```

Builtin that takes 2 sets and does an intersection on them

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](//github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
œ&
```

[Try it online!](//jelly.tryitonline.net#code=xZMm&args=WzMsMiwxXQ+Wy00LDMsNSw2XQ)

Explanation

```
 œ&  Main link. Arguments: x y
⁸    (implicit) x
   ⁹ (implicit) y
 œ&  Intersection of x and y
```